# Best process for proxysql?

Tags: mysql, java, proxysql

I have a java application, it connects to master database which has all the mysql users, password, jdbc url, etc. The permissions are set so that each tenant have access to their own database only.

I want to setup proxysql so that not only does the application connects to the master database but it also routes all traffic of each tenant from the proxysql.

I have added a user in mysql_user in proxysql which connects to only the master database. How and where do I add the other tenants mysql user based users so that the traffic is routed internally as well?

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Are multiple servers (or instances) of MySQL?

Comment: No, only 1 for now. We want to reduce the load on mysql. Will probably add more instances as we scale but not for now.